# Magento 1: How to join these tables to get the result

Tags: magento-1.9, product, customer, sales-order, join-table

```
$collection     = $this->_prepareEntityCollection(Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection'));

    foreach($collection as $customer){
       $_orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customer->getId());
       foreach($_orders as $_ordersitem){

                $orderid    =   $_ordersitem->getEntityId();
                $collection_sales = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->load($orderid);
                 $pro_id  =   $collection_sales->getProductId();
                $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pro_id);
                 echo '<pre>';print_r($_product->getCategoryIds());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please update what is the process you need to done?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query,

`SELECT 
    sales_order_item.order_id, 
    sales_order_item.product_id,
    sales_order.customer_id,
    catalog_category_product.category_id,
    catalog_category_entity_varchar.value
FROM 
    sales_order_item 
INNER JOIN
    sales_order ON sales_order_item.order_id = sales_order.entity_id
INNER JOIN 
    catalog_category_product ON sales_order_item.product_id = catalog_category_product.product_id
INNER JOIN 
    catalog_category_entity_varchar ON catalog_category_product.category_id = catalog_category_entity_varchar.entity_id
GROUP BY 
    catalog_category_product.category_id, sales_order.customer_id`